# Error al importar tensorflow js en node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, tensorflow, javascript-import

Quiero usar tensorflowjs en la terminal y copio el codigo de la pagina de npm y me sale un error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
                                                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
```

Yo instalé tensorflowjs con el flag "-g" porque no quiero crear un proyecto y instalarlo allí

Tengo node v11.5.0 y npm v6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Esto sucede porqué estas utilizando `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';` y probablemente no tienes configurado babel para utilizar el *import*.

prueba utilizando lo siguiente:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
```

Luego utiliza las funciones como salen en la documentación.